# Can magento use multiple MySQL slaves?

Tags: mysql, magento, replication

The following is part of my config for using a single slave.

```
<default_read>                 
    <connection>               
        <use/>                 
        <host><![CDATA[slavedb1.amazonaws.com]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[username]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[Password]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[shop]]></dbname>
        <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
        <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
        <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
        <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
        <active>1</active>  
    </connection>
</default_read>
```

However, I want to use **multiple slaves**. Is this possible with Magento?

To clarify, I have already got a single master/slave setup working with Magento already. I want to add another slave so that I have two slaves. I am wondering how the config will change to make use of this second slave.

Comment: what version of magento you are using ?

Comment: @Meabed I am using Magento version 1.7.0.2.

Comment: Could you share full xml ?

Comment: @Meabed To answer my question, I don't think you need to see my config  file. I just want to know how to use multiple slaves and whether this is even possible with Magento. Do you know if Magento can use multiple slaves?

Comment: you wanna use it only for write ? correct ?

Comment: Theoretically, yes you can duplicate all the queries to multiple database, it just need implementation in the write adapter. if you will only use it for write! ( if this will answer your question i will give you the solution ).

Comment: @Meabed I want to use the slaves for just reads and the master for write. I already have 1 master (write/read) and slave (read).I need more slaves (read).

Comment: Yes i see this is possible. for instance you set customers based on some criteria to read for other slave db ( like people with emails @gmail ) will read from salve1, ( customers with this ip address class ) will read from slave2 ? etc.. is this what you want ?

Comment: @Meabed To be honest, I want all reads (SELECT) to go to slaves, this is normally how a master/slave setup works. It's probably a good idea if you just show what you have by adding an answer, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware it is not possible to use multiple slaves with Magento.

If you are using AWS you could maybe use larger instances for your master/slave setup?

Comment: This is what I was afraid I would have to resort to but I think you're right. Magento doesn't have this functionality and the simplest thing for me to do is to just throw bigger hardware at the problem.

Comment: This is not entirely true.  While Magento, itself, does not *manage* multiple slaves that does not mean that an infrastructure cannot be designed to do TCP-based load balancing among various nodes.

Comment: I agree with Kevin, we are setting up replication and plan to have a shared VIP that will load balance all the slaves.  We will see how well that works!

Answer (score 2):

Given your comments above and assuming you have correct replication setup of your Databases.

#### Solution :-

### - Step 1:

In File

#### app/etc/config.xml

Find "core_read" Closing tag

```
<resources>
    ....
    <core_read>
            <connection>
                <use>default_read</use>
            </connection>
        </core_read>
    ....
</resources>
```

#### Add After the closing tag ( as many as databases you want to use ) it should look like below:

```
<resources>
    ....
        <core_read>
            <connection>
                <use>default_read</use>
            </connection>
        </core_read>
        <slave_db_1>
            <connection>
                <use>slave_one_db</use>
            </connection>
        </slave_db_1>
        <slave_db_2>
            <connection>
                <use>slave_two_db</use>
            </connection>
        </slave_db_2>
    ....
</resources>
```

### - Step 2:

#### And Add the new connection in your apt/etc/local.xml  after ( "/default_setup>" closing tag )

```
<resources>
    ....            
        <slave_one_db>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[slave_one_db_user]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[slave_one_db_password]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[slave_db_one_name]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </slave_one_db>
        <slave_two_db>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[slave_tow_db_user]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[slave_tow_db_password]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[slave_db_one_tow]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </slave_two_db>
    ....
</resources>
```

### - Step 3:

#### Copy the File From " app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php " == TO ==> " app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php "

1- Find  protected $_mappedTableNames;

2- Add this method below :

```
public function getSlaveDb()
{
    $prefix = 'slave_db_'; // prefix for the slaves databased in the xml file
    $cookieExpireTime = 1209600; // 2 weeks Cookie ( database selection ) expire time
    $dbArray = array(1,2); // All slaves Db in-case the cookie has invalid value
    $slaveDb = array_rand( array_flip($dbArray),1 ); // How to alternate between databases ( in this demo i just use 2 database ) adjust the selection of the database to fit hoe many database you want to use !
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['read_db']) || !in_array($_COOKIE['read_db'],$dbArray)) // Check for the cookie values
    {
        setcookie("read_db", $slaveDb, time()+$cookieExpireTime); // set the current database to the user in cookie so next time user use same connection to database ! to avoid jumping or hopping on different databases in short time
    }else{
        $slaveDb = $_COOKIE['read_db']; // return the database selected if the user has it in the cookies
    }
    return $prefix.$slaveDb;
}
```

3- Modify the method " public function getConnection($name) " to Look like below :

```
public function getConnection($name)
{
    if($name =='core_read') // Only applied for READ Connections !!!
    {
        $name = $this->getSlaveDb(); // change the name of the connection to the one we get from our main method
    }
    //....... Leave the rest of the function as it is !!
}
```

This will allow you to use as many as databases you specify in the XML and PHP CODE for core_read connection and the default_setup connection for all other connections in magento ( core_write, core_setup )

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: I am assuming, I can then add `slave_two_db` for the second slave?

Comment: yes, but by default magento using one connection for read only! and this is why i asked you do you wanna use more than db to read from for some people etc.. ? if you couldn't understand what i mean, lets chat

Comment: My question is very clear, it says `multiple slaves` not one slave. It is in bold. Multiple means more than one. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: The answer is solving exactly your issue ;) enjoy

Comment: Thank you for your long answer, I really appreciate it. However, I haven't tried it yet and I am not sure if its a good idea using cookies to determine what slave a user should use. I also do not want to edit core Magento files to get this to work.

Comment: LOL, Using cookies is only to prevent users from hopping on different database connections ( when they visit another page or refresh it ), ofcourse you can implement your own method of getting which slave Database you want the use to connect to! Last thing magento doesn't natively support your Question! ofcourse ! so this hack around is not Exactly core change ! its overriding 1 simple method in one file thats easly to adapt and keep track when you upgrade to newer Versions !!

Comment: The requires modifying core files which should not be done.  Simply use HA Proxy instead.

Comment: @kevin No Thats not true! its not core modifications it class priority loading !! and its very easy to maintain it as single method after you upgrade your magento when new version released! The other thing is my answer does something specifically and its NOT achievable with HA Proxy !! sorry i have to say your comment is extremely useless.

Comment: Yes, your example does something specific that HAProxy does not do (having user-based slave preference), for good reason.  This solution does not balance load and it does not have fault tolerance.  In fact, *if a slave goes down this solution will cause temporary failures for anyone who has a certain cookie set until the slave comes back online*.  You can use HAProxy as a TCP load balancer with HA and it will manage all of this for you

Comment: balance, as part of the CentOS distro is also useful if you want to do the balancing on the web nodes itself.  However, it means maintaining consistent configuration on the nodes.  But if it's a small installation then it should work fine.

Comment: Another problem with this code is that if you need to add a third slave machine you need to make code modifications in order to handle it.

Comment: Yes but my code was intentionally made for people without much of hardware resources, and its very easy to modify to have fallback goes back to the original database etc..! so again your comment wasn't in the place that should be! its just justifications .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your solution over here. [Need help writing to multiple database through single Magento installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775114/need-help-writing-to-multiple-database-through-single-magento-installation)

I think this is what is required

Comment: Please read my question again. I have no issue with setting up a slave and using it. I want to use multiple slaves and I am wondering how the config will change.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the best setup would be to use a Load Balancer to spread reads across the multiple slaves.

The reason behind this , is that with a Load Balancer, if any Slave dies , there will be very little seen from Magento itself (the customers). If you use Mageneto's method of multiple slaves, then if one slave is down, a query will need to timeout before it can be sent to another node (customers will see lag on the frontend).

I have used Stingray/Zeus (Commercial Product) but I've also seen HAProxy used for this.

Comment: This is something I was considering including making use of mysqlproxy. However, this introduces another component to my architecture which I really do not want to support/maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Someone is reading this thread again:

The Codesnippets written by Meabed are still valid, if you want to use single master with multiple slaves in magento.
magento's default setup, doesnt support multiple slaves.

First take a look at
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php -> function getConnection( $name )

This function returns the correct connection for de current query. E.g. Master Connection for Write Queries and Slave Connection for 
Read Queries.

The passed variable $name, defines which Connection should be used. 
This Code ( about Line 95 )

```
$connConfig = Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig($name);
```

returns the Read or Write Connection.

So there are only a few modifications needed, to work with multiple slaves.
First Modify your local.xml

```
<default_setup>
    <connection>
        <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[yourdatabase]]></dbname>
        <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
        <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
        <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
        <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
        <active>1</active>
    </connection>
</default_setup>    

<slave_db_one>
    <connection>
        <use />
        <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.3]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[yourdatabase]]></dbname>
        <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
        <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
        <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
        <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
        <active>1</active>
    </connection>
</slave_db_one>                          

<slave_db_two>
    <connection>
        <use />
        <host><![CDATA[127.0.02]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[yourdatabase]]></dbname>
        <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
        <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
        <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
        <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
        <active>1</active>
    </connection>
</slave_db_two>
```

So only add two more nodes after the closing tag of your default connection.

As "Meabed" descripted some days ago, you only need to modify the variable "$name" in a way to get the correct connection node.
e.g. put this at the top of the method "getConnection"

```
if ( $name == 'core_read' ) {
$name   = 'slave_db_two';
```

}

You can also write an function and return random another connection name.

```
public function getRunningSlave() {
$input = array("slave_db_one", "slave_db_two");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
return $input[$rand_keys[0]];
```

}

Another way, check with SHOW SLAVE STATUS the state of the slave, if the slave is currently offline, get another connection or return master connection for reading queries.

cheers